# XSLT and MathJax

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, mathjax, tei

I am new to XSLT and StackOverflow. I'm trying to use the [TEI Boilerplate](http://www.teiboilerplate.org) stylesheet to render a TEI document in the browser. All goes well until I try get MathJax to render the formulae. I've modified the teibp.xsl from my local copy of TEI Boilerplate to include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

just before the `</head>` tag in the htmlHead template. However, when I load the document in the browser, MathJax doesn't render the formula at all and I just get the LaTeX markup as I typed it into the XML file. I have tried moving the call to MathJax.js around - to the top of the header, to various points in the body - but no luck. I've also tried loading the page and then loading a [MathJax bookmarklet](http://checkmyworking.com/misc/mathjax-bookmarklet/) but that doesn't get it to render either.

Am I doing something really stupid? Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? I'm pasting a minimal XML file below, which works with TEIBP other than the MathJax rendering.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="teibp.xsl"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_allPlus.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
   <teiHeader>
      <fileDesc>
         <titleStmt>
            <title>MathJax test</title>
         </titleStmt>
         <publicationStmt>
            <p>2015</p>
         </publicationStmt>
         <sourceDesc>
            <p>Born digital</p>
         </sourceDesc>
      </fileDesc>
      <encodingDesc>
         <p>Born digital</p>
      </encodingDesc>
   </teiHeader>
   <text>

      <body>
         <p>\(ax^2+bx+c=0\)</p>
      </body>
   </text>
</TEI>
```

Comment: In your question there are spaces after "...config=TeX-" in the script tag loading MathJax. That would break things in a live page.

Comment: Thanks - I think that's a blip from when I was trying to indent it in the SO editor. It's correct in my xsl file (and I've corrected it on here now).

Comment: Well, what does the error console of your browser show (hit F12 to open the developer tools), are there any Javascript errors shown?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the stylesheet you use transforms the XML to XHTML with `xsl:output method="xml"`, it looks as if that combination (XHTML generated as result of client-side XSLT) together with MathJax breaks, at least it does in a simple test case like http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015092902.xml in both Firefox (error message "TypeError: this.div.style is undefined") and Chrome ("Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined"). In a similar test case http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015092903.xml that transforms to HTML with no namespaces used and `xsl:output method="html"` the combination of XSLT and MathJax works (meaning the mathematic formula is rendered). A simple test of MathJax with static XHTML (i.e. a static XHTML document) however shows that MathJax can handle XHTML. So you either need someone to fix MathJax to handle the X(HT)ML result of a client-side XSLT transformation or you need to try to fix the stylesheet you have to create HTML with no namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and I resolved it loading dynamically the MathJax script:

```
<script>//<![CDATA[
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/mml-svg.js';
  document.head.appendChild(script);
//]]></script>
```